# Client Wants Free things for project

Tags: freelance-websites

I'm a freelance web developer who works with foreign clients.

I have worked with multiple clients , you can say me newbie to this, not in web development field but in this freelancing.

I'm working with a client for a long time and never missed any deadlines nor made any mistakes on any project. he was nice at start and it is getting worse.

Nowadays, after each project completion , he wants to add things in his project which developed by my for free. I usually provide a month free bug fixing and support via email.

So, i'm looking for some advice to what to do in this situation and how other freelancers handles it. just needs some advice.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand, either tell him "No." or tell him what the charges will be. If you ask your local plumber for free services, what would he tell you? Same thing applies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first best thing you can do is make the client agree to a straightforward and clear contract. Specify what services are included and what ones will be additional charges.

If you do this, from now on you can politely, but firmly, say something like:

"I'm sorry to hear about that, I would be happy to fix it. As a reminder my included support window expired last week so any additional support will be charged at $___/hour"

There is no reason you should be working for free!

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much, i'm following your advice,
Have a good day!

Comment: No problem! I hope it helps!